# How to get coupon code in newsletter subscription Email Template in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, coupon-codes, newsletter-subscriber

get coupon code in the newsletter email template.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is possible.

1. Create A cart rules from admin > Marketing > Cart Rules.

2.Create observer event email_newsletter_set_template_vars_before.So, at this event you can add new parameter via transport to template means you can create coupon and send to email.

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/events.xml

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Observer/ObserverforAddCustomVariable.php

class ObserverforAddCustomVariable implements ObserverInterface
{

```
protected $ruleFactory;
protected $massgenerator;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Massgenerator $massgenerator, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger ) {
    $this->ruleFactory= $ruleFactory;
    $this->massgenerator = $massgenerator;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
    $transport = $observer->getTransport();
    $transport['free-coupon'] = "FREE2020";
}
```

}

3. At the email template , you can get this custom variables free-coupon using {{var free-coupon|raw}}

Comment: There is no such event like email_newsletter_set_template_vars_before.